# Python: building a tree with data in nodes and arcs

Tags: python, tree

I'm trying to build a tree with data in the nodes as well as in the arcs. What I did so far is build classes Tree, Arc and Node like this:

```
class Tree():

  def __init__(self):
    self.root = None
    self.nodes = {}
    self.end_arcs = {}

class Arc():

  def __init__(self,start,end,data={}):
    self.start = start
    self.end = end
    self.data = data

class Node():

  def __init__(self,token,data={}):
    self.token = str(token)
    self.state = self.OPEN
    self.data = data
```

Nodes are numbered increasingly with the end node being labeled as -1. However, when I want to reverse the tree and renumber the nodes, I have to change a lot of things: the keys of my nodes dict, the label of every node and perhaps (or can they point to the nodes in my nodes dict?) also the nodes in my arcs dict. So I'm thinking that my way of implementing this common structure is not a good one. Is there a standard way of solving this problem? Or how would you build a tree structure like this?

Thanks in advance,

Joris

Comment: Are your arc endpoints the nodes (the node objects) or the node IDs?  It sounds like you are storing the node IDs.  You might consider storing the node references.

Comment: I'm storing the nodes. I'm pretty new to Python, so does this mean that if I change the nodes in my nodes dict that the nodes in my arcs are automatically changed as well (pass by reference)?

Comment: If you paste more code we could answer that.  Its not really clear what you're doing when you're "changing node in the node dict" so its hard to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending my comment a bit, consider the following

```
class Tree():
  def __init__(self):
    self.root = None
    self.nodes = {}
    self.end_arcs = {}

class Arc():
  def __init__(self,start,end,data={}):
    self.start = start
    self.end = end
    self.data = data

  def __str__(self):
    return "%s-%s" % (self.start.token, self.end.token)

class Node():
  def __init__(self,token,data={}):
    self.token = str(token)
    #self.state = self.OPEN
    self.data = data


n1 = Node(1)
n2 = Node(2)
n3 = Node(3)
n4 = Node(4)
n5 = Node(5)

t = Tree()
t.root = n1
t.nodes = [n1,n2,n3,n4,n5]

a1 = Arc(n1,n2)
a2 = Arc(n2,n3)
a3 = Arc(n2,n4)
a4 = Arc(n1,n5)

print(a1)  # 1-2
# "Rename" Nodes
n1.token = 101 
n2.token = 102
print(a1)  # 101-102
```

"Renaming" the nodes is no problem because the arc keeps tracks of the node "by reference", not by it's ID.  When we look at, for example, the arcs, using references allow us to not care about how the underlying node is changed.

Comment: That's nice, one thing less to worry about :-). I notice you store the nodes in a list though. Doesn't this make it hard to find them by token? Or do you want to loop over all of them to find the node you are looking for? That's the reason why I used a dict, but of course now the tokens are stored as keys too which uses more memory and it is harder to change the tokens...

Comment: The problem with storing them in a dictionary is that you would need to update the dictionary keys every time you updated the token.  You could do this of course, for example by creating a `set_token()` method which would update the token as well as the dictionary key.  This might be a better way than searching through the entire node list if you're doing it frequently or there are a lot of nodes.  Otherwise, "manually" searching through the list isn't that big of a deal.

Comment: Since I'm working with rather large trees, I will go for the dictionary. Resetting the keys is not so trivial though (seems you have to completely rebuild your dict?!), but I guess that's off-topic. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want to implement this graph infrastructure yourself, take a look at [NetworkX](http://networkx.lanl.gov/tutorial/tutorial.html). It is a feature-full graph/network library and it's easy to get started.

```
import networkx as nx

class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from([Node(1), Node(2), Node(3), Node(4)])
G.add_edge(1, 2, data='some data')
G.add_edge(2, 3, data='some more data')
G.add_edge(2, 4, data='yet more data')
```

This creates a graph that looks like

```
  1
  |
  2
 / \
/   \
|   |
3   4
```

You need not use a custom class for the nodes. You can simply use strings, integers etc. (any hashable object).

Comment: how do you evaluate the tree paths? 1,2,3 and 1,2,4  what function generates the pathes